# Boxing in after knock-through

Tags: drywall

I have just had a knock-through done and was wondering about boxing-in the gap ready for plastering.

I know the process for boxing in the steel beam, but where the hole was made there is now an uneven part of the wall one brick thick. I'm not sure dot and dab will work, as the wall is thin.

I was wondering how people go about attaching plaster-board/tidying this up.

Thanks!

Comment: What is a "knock-through"?

Comment: Took out a load bearing wall between two rooms. A steel beam has been put in, but where the wall has been knocked down the edges are very uneven.

Comment: Please post pictures.